# How do you arrive at these two probability formulas?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In probability, if you are counting an ordered set with repetitions not allowed, how and why does the formula $N(N - 1)(N - 2)...(N - (n - 1))$ become $\frac{N!}{(N - n)!}$ in its concise form?

I was told that multiplying the formula by $\frac{(N - n)!}{(N - n)!}$ gives the concise form, how do you multiply the first formula by that number?

Second question:
If you are counting an unordered set with repetitions not allowed this time, the formula becomes
$\frac{N}{n} = \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}$, where a $n!$ was added in the denominator to remove the overcounting, how and why was the $n!$ added in that specific place?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you have $N$ choices for the first selection, $N-1$ choices for the second selection, and so on up to $N-(n-1)$ choices for the $n$th selection.  So

$$N (N - 1) (N - 2) \cdots (N - (n - 1)) 
\\=N (N - 1) (N - 2) \cdots (N - (n - 1)) \dfrac{(N - n)(N - n - 1)\cdots 1}{(N - n)(N - n - 1)\cdots 1}
\\= \dfrac{N (N - 1) (N - 2) \cdots (N - (n - 1))(N - n)(N - n - 1)\cdots 1}{(N - n)(N - n - 1)\cdots 1}
\\= \dfrac{N!}{(N-n)!}$$

ways of making the ordered selection of $n$ from $N$.

For the second part, you have $${N \choose n} = \dfrac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}$$ because the $n$ selections can come in any $n!$ different ways which you want to treat as the same selection.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

Look at $N=5$ and $n=3$.

Then you have

$$5\cdot4\cdot3=5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot\frac{2\cdot1}{2\cdot1}=\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{2\cdot1}=\frac{5!}{(5-3)!}$$

Second question:

You take $n$ elements out of the set. If you care about the ordering, the first formula holds. But if you dont, how many orderings are there for the $n$ elements? Exactly $n!$.

Thus, if you want to compute the number of different sets, but without ordering you just compute the number of different ordered sets, but divide by $n!$.